# Showing an algebra is not a sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why the green underline is correct? I assume the $i's$ and  $n's$ have got mixed up, but i'm still confused.

Comment: Let me try to help clarify what's written here: $i$ and $n$ are dummy variables, so their actual names aren't important. $n$ used in the definition of $\Sigma_0$, however, is dummy for the description of the set $\Sigma_0$, not for the union, while $n$ used in the last statement is dummy for $\bigcup$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\bigcup\limits_{n\ge2} [y_n,1)$ arises from the definition of a sigma-algebra, because sigma-algebras need to be closed under countable union.

This does not relate to the definition of $\Sigma_0$ in terms of certain finite unions $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i)$.

The double use of $n$ is perhaps a bit unfortunate. We could also have written $\bigcup\limits_{m\ge2} [y_m,1)$; the meaning is not different.

---

The bottom line is this:

- $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i)$ describes *one* element of $\Sigma_0$;
- $\bigcup\limits_{m\ge2} [y_m,1)$ describes a *union* of elements from $\Sigma_0$. It is of the same kind as: $$\bigcup_{m \ge 2} \Big((-\infty,-y_m) \cup [y_m, 1)\Big)$$ which perhaps makes the distinction between these two a bit more apparent.